# Public google calender iframe not showing any events

Tags: html, css, iframe, calendar, embed

**My calender is public** (should be anyway) **, however not showing any of my events**. I made the calender public quite some time ago, thought it might take some time, waited at least 20 days but no change, still **none of the events are showing in the embedded calender**. Any tips/pointers what i might be doing wrong?

I made the calender public with the checkbox "make available to public" under "Access permission and events" and chose the option "see only free/busy (hide details)".  See image below[image]

I have updated the iframe link in my html code after changing settings to make the calender public but it's still not showing any of the events from my calender.

website (calender is at the bottom):
[kakelbonthuisje.nl](https://kakelbonthuisje.nl)

**iframe code/link:**

```
<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?height=600&wkst=1&bgcolor=%23ffffff&ctz=Europe%2FAmsterdam&src=a2FrZWxib250aHVpc2plQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ&color=%23039BE5" style="border:solid 1px #777" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

full code can be found here:
https://github.com/MaartenDominicus/Huisje

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that although i had set my calendar to be publicly visible, the events inside the calendar themselves were set to "automatic" visibility instead of "public" visibility. Setting these to "public" visibility made them show up in the embedded agenda.

These events (which weren't showing up) must have been from before i had set the agenda itself to "public" visibility and it seems like the existing events in the calendar don't automatically get set to "public" when the agenda's overall visibility gets changed to "public".